# How to do following formatting using sed or awk or bash script on linux

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

Suppose, I have two files:
`file1` having below contents.

```
message_aaa.wav
  test 1 of 1
    test Label        : aaa
    test Sentence       : test aaa
    test String: test message
    Interpretation Score : 567
message_bbb.wav
  test 1 of 1
    test Label        : bbb
    test Sentence       : test bbb
    test String: test bbb
    Interpretation Score : 972
Message_ccc.wav
  test 1 of 1
    test Label        : ccc
    test Sentence       : ccc
    test String: test ccc
    Interpretation Score : 921
```

`file2` having below contents:

```
message_aaa.wav
  test 1 of 1
    test Label        : aaa
    test Sentence       : test aaa
    test String: test message
    Interpretation Score : 55
message_bbb.wav
  test 1 of 1
    test Label        : bbb
    test Sentence       : test bbb
    test String: test bbb
    Interpretation Score : 34
message_ccc.wav
  test 1 of 1
    test Label        : ccc
    test Sentence       : ccc
    test String: test ccc
    Interpretation Score : 12
```

I want to create one `CSV`/`xls` file, which will have 3 columns as:
1st column will be name of `.wav` files from `file1`
2nd column will be "Interpretation score" `from file1`
3rd column will be "Interpretation score" `from file2`
like below.

```
message_aaa.wav,567,55
message_bbb.wav,972,34
message_ccc.wav,921,12
```

Comment: @choroba I tried to read both files line by line, but struggling to join lines containing '.wav' and scores from two files.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to do this with a bash script?  Something like this would be really easy with Python for example.

Comment: trivial in perl, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a perl script that does the job.  It reads through stdin, and extracts the filenames to use as the key to a hashed array called `%wavfiles`.  The particular data structure used is a hash-of-arrays, a hashed array where each element is a list (i.e. an array) containing one or more values.

When it sees a line matching the regex `/Interpretation Score/` AND if `$filename` is non-empty, it uses `split()` to extract the interpretation score and push it onto the array contained in `$wavfiles{$filename}`.  It then clears `$filename` to prevent spurious data being added for that key.

When there is no more input to be read, it prints out the contents of the `%wavfiles` hash-of-arrays in CSV format.

This script will work with any number of input files, of any size.  It treats all filenames specified on the command line and/or all data piped in from stdin as one input stream.

The order of the input is significant - it directly affects the order of the Interpretation Scores in the output (e.g. if it sees 567 before 55, that is the order it will display those values.  and vice-versa).

The script is not limited to just two Interpretation Scores for each filename - it will print as many it sees for each filename, separated by commas in the order that it saw them.

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my %wavfiles = ();
my $filename = '';

while(<>) {
    chomp;    # strip line-feed from end of line

    $filename = $_ if (m/\.wav$/);

    if ((m/Interpretation Score/) && (! -z $filename)) {
        my (undef,$score) = split /: /;     # split input line on ': '
        push @{ $wavfiles{$filename} }, $score;
        $filename = '';
    };
}   

foreach $filename (keys %wavfiles) {
    print "$filename,", join(",",@{ $wavfiles{$filename} }),"\n";
}
```

Output using your sample input is:

```
$ ./interpscore.pl file1 file2
message_bbb.wav,972,34
Message_ccc.wav,921
message_aaa.wav,567,55
message_ccc.wav,12
```

Note that hash keys, like filenames, are case-sensitive, which is why there is an entry for both `Message_ccc.wav` (with a capital-M) and `message_ccc.wav` (with a lowercase-m) - that's what was in your input files.  You need to edit your input files so that the filenames are consistent - after you do that, the output will be:

```
$ ./interpscore.pl file1 file2
message_aaa.wav,567,55
message_ccc.wav,921,12
message_bbb.wav,972,34
```

Comment: thanks @cas . One more thing to confirm, Above script will work even if wav file name contains any other string instead of message_ ..e.g like lisa_bbb.wav

Comment: yep, it searches for `\.wav$` (a literal period `\.` followed by `wav` at the end of the line `$`).  see the second non-blank line after the `while(<>) {`.  you can edit that line so that it matches whatever you like.  e.g. If you wanted it to match only your message_ filenames, you'd change the regexp to `/^message_...\.wav$/`

Comment: BTW, one thing i should have mentioned in my answer - the field output order depends on the order of the input files.  So if you run it as `./interpscore file2 file1` rather than `./interpscore.pl file1 file2` then, e.g., the `message_aaa.wav` line will look like this: `message_aaa.wav,55,567` - in other words, the script will add the scores for each file in the order it sees them.

Comment: Also, it's not limited to just 2 scores for each filename - it will handle as many as it sees, whether that's 1 or 2 or 10000 or whatever, and print them all out separated by commas.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this with `awk`:

```
awk '/^[mM]essage_.*.wav/{
    n=NR+5;i=tolower($1)
}
n==NR{
    a[i]=a[i]","$4
}
END{
    for ( i in a){
        print i""a[i]
    }
}' file1 file2
```

If the line starts with `[mM]essage_.*.wav` the variable `n` is set to `NR+5` (The line numbers where `Interpretation Score` value is) and the wav file name is saved in variable a `i`.

When `n==NR` and array with index as `i` is created and `Interpretation Score`($4) is appended to this array.

`END` print all the array index and its value as desired.

Here I assumed the `Interpretation Score` line always as the 5th line in each test.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -e 'wav\|Inter' file1.txt | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}'| awk 'NR%2{printf $0",";next;}1' > file1new.txt
grep -e 'wav\|Inter' file2.txt | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}'| awk 'NR%2{printf $0",";next;}1' > file2new.txt
join -t, file1new.txt file2new.txt
```